# What is the iDOT chunk

Tags: ios, macos, png, retina-display, file-format

Looking at a screenshot I took on a MacBook Pro with Retina display and running OS X 10.11, I found that it contained these chunks:

```
IHDR, iCCP, pHYs, iTXt, iDOT, IDAT…, IEND
```

All of these are part of [the 2003 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110), except for `iDOT` which is a small (28 bytes) chunk. According to the [chunk naming conventions](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#5Chunk-naming-conventions), the fact that its second letter is capital should indicate that it's a chunk with a public specification. I couldn't find its specification anywhere yet though. It's not listed in the [Register of public PNG chunks and keywords, Version 1.4.6](http://libpng.org/pub/png/spec/register/pngreg-1.4.6-pdg.html) either, although that appears to be [the latest version](ftp://ftp.simplesystems.org/pub/png/documents/).

There are many sites on the web mentioning that chunk, including many on Stack Overflow. Most are describing error messages along the lines of

```
ImageIO: PNG invalid PNG file: iDOT doesn't point to valid IDAT chunk
```

and those which got resolved found out some kind of image corruption not neccessarily due to this chunk, or applied some conversion which presumably also deleted this chunk.

Many pages also mention Retina displays. It is my guess and hope that this chunk somehow indicates the display density in effect when the screenshot was taken. That would be massively useful for [automatic scaling of screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161111/checkbox-to-include-img-html-or-automatically-resize-a-retina-display-screens).

*Edit:* Taking some more screenshots, I find that indeed the pixel density seems to play a part: running the display at native resolution I get no such chunk and the image dimensions as shown while taking the screenshot. Only at higher density do I get the chunk and a PNG image size which is an integer multiple of the displayed one. The 28 bytes of data seem to represent 7 little-endian 32-bit integers. For me these were `(2, 0, h, 40, h, h, x)` where `2` presumably indicates the pixel density, `h` is the apparent image height (i.e. half the one actually stored) and `x` is some number I don't understand at all. I don't know how fractional pixel densities would enter this game.

Where can one find details and perhaps even a specification for this chunk? Do I have to contact Apple or the registry, or is there someone here who can provide more details?

Comment: I confirm that "iDOT" is not a registered PNG chunk.

Comment: I've also asked about this on the [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/90241).

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with CgBI PNGs.  They contain a different IDAT than what appears in valid PNG files.

Comment: "According to the chunk naming conventions, the fact that its second letter is capital should indicate that it's a chunk with a public specification" Another case of Apple abusing an open standard.

Comment: You could also ask at [png-mng-misc@lists.sourceforge.net](https://sourceforge.net/p/png-mng/mailman/png-mng-misc/), but as far as I see nobody (from Apple) tried to register it yet, neither there nor at the official (but seemingly defunct) address for that purpose, which is [png-group@w3.org](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/png-group/). Then again, @GlennRanders-Pehrson has already read it here and who else is gonna reply there?

Comment: @Crissov: I agree that asking on png lists is unlikely to yield new information. The Apple dev forum post has remained unanswered. I'm trying to think of ways to escalate this with Apple. I don't know about any suitable Apple channels, though. Perhaps I should apply for my own and incompatible variant of an `iDOT` chunk, just to show Apple the point of following a registration procedure. Might seem somewhat preposterous, though.

Comment: I just filed bug 24483289 about this. Not sure whether a bug report is the appropriate channel, but the forum didn't yield any reaction.

Comment: This blog article was able to reverse engineer some data of this chunk: https://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/895-Connecting-the-iDOTs.html
The author even mentions this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hendrik already wrote in a comment, https://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/895-Connecting-the-iDOTs.html has reverse-engineered the purpose of this chunk. It contains an offset to a well-defined position in the encoded image data. Right after a flush so decompressor state is reset, and also right at an IDAT chunk boundary, and with a known pixel position at half the height of the image.

The purpose of that is to allow decoding the image data in parallel on multi-core processors. This goal has recently (2021-12-01) been confirmed in a comment on that page from someone involved with the implementation. That comment, albeit still far from official, is there most authoritative I could find on this issue so far.