# Tkinter PhotoImage error "encountered an unsupported criticial chunk type "iDOT""

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to show an image on screen with python and tkinter, but when I run it, it gives an error in the PhotoImage object.
This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
photo = PhotoImage(file="devil.png")
label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The image file is in the same folder as the .py file.

And it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/MyUsername/PycharmProjects/GUI test/home.py", line 5, in <module>
photo = PhotoImage(file="devil.png")
File "C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3542, in __init__
Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
File "C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3498, in __init__
self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: encountered an unsupported criticial chunk type "iDOT"
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried a different image? I have ran your sample using my own .png, it worked fine. What system are you on etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was indeed the file that did not work

Comment: :) No problem. Cebrail has added a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chunk type of image you're using, 'iDOT', is not a registered PNG chunk. So, you should replace the image with an appropriate one.

[This can help you understand what actually error is about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33894790/what-is-the-idot-chunk)